# Understanfing OpenIE 5 output

Tags: information-retrieval, information-extraction, triples

I used your [Open IE](https://github.com/dair-iitd/OpenIE-standalone) 5 to extract the triples and got the following result,

**Text Input**
By the algorithmic approach known as LevenbergMarquardt backpropagation algorithm, the error is decreased repeatedly. Some ANN models employ supervisory training while others are referred to as none-supervisory or self-organizing training. However, the vast majority of ANN models use supervisory the supervisory training. The training phase may consume a lot of time. In the supervisory training, the actual output of ANN is compared with the desired output. The training set consists of presenting input and output data to the network. The network adjusts the weighting coefficients, which usually begin with random set, so that the next iteration will produce a closer match between the desired and the actual the actual output of ANN. The training method tries to minimize the current errors for all processing elements. This global error reduction is created over time by continuously modifying the

**Output**

```
0.89 Context(The training method tries,List([723, 748))):(The training method; tries to minimize; the current errors for all processing elements)
0.95 (the vast majority of ANN models; use; supervisory the supervisory training)
0.88 (others; are referred; as self - organizing training)
0.89 Context(The training method tries,List([717, 742))):(The training method; tries to minimize; the current errors for all processing elements)
0.93 Context(Some ANN models employ The training phase may consume,List([120, 340))):(the error; is decreased; T:repeatedly; T:By the algorithmic approach)
0.94 Context(The training phase may consume,List([310, 340))):(Some ANN models; employ; supervisory training; while others are referred to as self - organizing training)
0.89 Context(The training method tries,List([724, 749))):(The training method; tries to minimize; the current errors for all processing elements)
0.93 Context(The training phase may consume,List([311, 341))):(the vast majority of ANN models; use; supervisory the supervisory training)
0.93 Context(Some ANN models employ The training phase may consume,List([120, 341))):(the error; is decreased; T:repeatedly; T:By the algorithmic approach)
0.94 Context(The training phase may consume,List([311, 341))):(Some ANN models; employ; supervisory training; while others are referred to as none - supervisory training)
0.92 (This global error reduction; is created; T:over time; by continuously modifying the)
```

Can anyone please help me understanding,

- What is  *List([723, 748))):*
- *T:over time;*
- In some case it has 4 entities, (*the error; is decreased; T:repeatedly; T:By the algorithmic approach*)

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer "What is List([723, 748))):?"
I think this is the location/span of the context phrase in the input sentence.
T:over time; This is tagging the role as Time. i.e "over time" is a time role in SRL.
In some case it has 4 entities, (the error; is decreased; T:repeatedly; T:By the algorithmic approach): OpenIE sometimes gives an n-ary relation extraction besides the usual triple extraction.